# CakePHP 1.3 controller save() does not save data

Tags: cakephp, controller, save, cakephp-1.3

I want to add a new user to the database, and do so by making them fill in a form and submitting this. All seems to work fine. Just before my `save()` call in the controller I return all data and all necessary data is there. It is valid(ated), since no errors are returned.

But then nothing happens. I'm being returned to my form without any errors being shown.
This is my 'save-line':

```
if($this->Registratie->save($this->data)) {
```

I'm not making use of any `beforeSave()` methods.

Using `debug($this->validationErrors);` shows:

```
app/controllers/registratie_controller.php (line 45)
```

Which is the line of code from above.

I've been going through my code over and over. What could the problem be?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($this->Registratie->save($this->data));`?

Comment: You *return* the data? I believe you rather dump it, because returning would break the control flow.

Comment: What is the format of your $this->data array? Is the keys of this array do not match, it will not save, and will not throw an error

Answer (score 1):

When you create a form using the FormHelper it will generate input names like:

```
<input type='text' name='data[Registratie][first_name]'>
```

Once the form is submitted cake will push that into the $this->data array with an index of 'Registratie'

You probably need to pass the index to the model when saving

```
if ($this->Registratie->save( $this->data['Registratie'] ) ) {
```

I would also do a **var_dump($this->data)** or **print_r($this->data)** to make sure your form fields are coming through.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, fixed doing exactly what Jack B Nimble told. Using CakePHP 1.3

Sample:

Model: Contacts

```
$this->data['contact']
```